# Testflight vs. App Store Installation (without loosing data)

Tags: ios, deployment, testflight

We want our testers to be able to:

1) Replace an installed Tesflight version of our app (test-version) when installing the App Store released version of our app (app_store-version) without loosing their data (all inside the app bundle, Core Data and other DBs, Keychain data, User Defaults).

2) vice versa

Replace an installed app_store-version with an test-version without loosing the above mentioned data.

The only information I found is in the Testflight documentation:

> ...If you already have the live version of the app installed on your
>   device, the beta version of the app will replace the live version.
>   When you’ve downloaded the beta app, you’ll see an orange dot next to
>   its name that identifies it as a beta. ...

I did not find any information regarding the opposite case (... if you already have a test-version installed, the app_store-version will replace it...) nor if the above mentioned data is kept when replacing the app.

Apple Developer Support told me that they do not have this knowledge. :-/

My Questions are:

1) Is is possible to replace a Tesflight version of our app (test-version) with a App Store released version of our app (app_store-version) without loosing the above mentioned data?

2) Is is possible to replace a App Store released version of our app (app_store-version) with a Tesflight version of our app (test-version) without loosing the above mentioned data?

3) If 1+2 is possible, which parameters are taken into account to replace/ not replace an app? (BundleID only, BundleID & BundleVersion ...)

Answer (score -1):

You can override TestFlight and App Store version like regular updates. But, in order to do that, the `Next Version` should have a build number greater than the installed one.

That means that you cannot install the TestFlight version, release it on the App Store and upgrade, because the build numbers will be the same

Comment: Means: In both directions the app is replaced, keeping app bundle data if: 1) app ID is the same 2) build number > installed build number? What would happen if the build number is the same? Two installed apps? Replace app loosing data?

Comment: No, you cannot have the 2 app with same bundle Ids. And you cannot override an app by a second one ( matching bundle Id ) if the distribution Profile doesn't match. And finally, if the distribution profile matches, you will see an AppStore "Update" if the build version is greater.

Comment: So the answers are: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. 3) Bundle ID == installed Bundle ID AND (bundleVersion > installed.bundleVersion OR (bundleVersion == installed.bundleVersion AND buildNum > installed.buildNum))?

Comment: Yes that's it. But don't forget the distribution profile part.

Comment: What "distribution profile part" are you referring to? Could you maybe extend your answer to be explicit in regards to what has to be taken into account to achieve the goals mentioned?